# latex doesn't display carriage returns from mysql query

Tags: mysql, latex

In a textarea of an html form I allow multi line inputs such as:

---

hello

goodbye

---

This string is then put into a mysql database with mysql_real_escape_string.
Now I want to take this string and pass it directly into a tex document, but the empty lines (carriage returns I suppose) are not being output with the string. Hence when this is compiled with latex I get the output

---

hellornrngoodbye

---

What do I need to do to my string to retain the carriage returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After our discussion in chat, here's what we figured out:

You used

```
shell_exec("cat ".$PATH."/LatexTemplate.tex | sed -e 's/LatexCode/$latexcode/' > ".$PATH."/TexFiles/Q$id.tex");
```

inside a PHP script to insert the latex input stored in the DB into a template file and save that. Somewhere in this process, the newlines got dropped.

The best solution would be to replace the shell exec with a PHP equivalent that loads the file into a string, performs a string replacement with the (unescaped) input string and stores it in another file.

Comment: I did try this: `$str = str_replace('\r\n','\\',$str);` but all I got was this inserted into my tex file: _hello\goodbye_. Which isn't correct.

Comment: Geoff: That's because you are doing the replace in a language which uses `\\` as an escape character. See my edit :)

Comment: Yes, I tried this too, and in this case it works! BUT Let's say I want to continue with \begin{enumerate} (CR) \item hi (CR) \end{enumerate}, then I get \\ in my tex file before the \item and then that doesn't work. So ideally I would like really an empty space/carriage return parsed into the tex source rather than simulating it with \\.

Comment: ps: how can I do line breaks in the comments? I hit enter, and the comment is posted!

Comment: @Geoff: I don't follow. Can you edit the original question to include this example?

Comment: want to sort this out in chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/7009/latex-doesnt-display-carriage-returns-from-mysql-query?tab=general